# How to return List in a single line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get a list of integers into a single line without spaces, I was able to do the below code

```
import sys

l = [1, 2, 3]
for a in list:
    b = sys.stdout.write(str(a))
return int(b)
```

but the above code gives me an out put of `1231`, but I want the output as `123`

does any one have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: last return not needed

Comment: why not use `print` instead of `sys.stdout.write()`? Also, please don't name your variables things like `list`, `dict`, `str`, etc. - those are built-in Python functions, and you are masking them.

Comment: @MattDMo if i use print I am getting a new line but i want this to return to a new function

Comment: now that you changed your list name to `l` you also have to iterate over  `l`

Comment: `return list(map(str([1,2,3])))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just trying to return a string of the list items all concatenated together, your code should be:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
return ''.join([str(item) for item in l])
```

No need for importing `sys` or writing to stdout.

If the output needs to be an int, just use

```
return int(''.join([str(item) for item in l]))
```

I know it looks a little weird to cast ints to strings, back to ints, but that's what you have to do if you want to concatenate everything.

Comment: @AvinashRaj not for me, using 3.4.2. What version are you using?

Comment: it's because you have to define a function that returns the value. Now get `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`

Comment: You don't need that extra list - `''.join(str(item) for item in [1,2,3])` works fine, or another option is `list(map(str, [1,2,3])))`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid nope not working, it gives me a list, where as `''.join(str(item) for item in [1,2,3])` combines a list into one

Comment: Ah yes, you need `''.join(map(str, [1,2,3]))`